# How to count all instance in the join for each row?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, join

I have the following scheme:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `answers` (
`id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
`answer` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
`username` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
`date` datetime NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`username`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `answers` (`id`, `answer`, `username`, `date`) VALUES
(1, 'gfdsf', 'guy', '2012-12-22 00:00:00'),
(4, 'gfdddsfs', 'maricela', '2012-12-22 00:00:00'),
(4, 'gfddsfs', 'mikha', '2012-12-22 00:00:00'),
(4, 'gfdsfs', 'guy', '2012-12-22 00:00:00');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `questions` (
`id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`asker_username` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
`target_username` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
`question` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
`hide` enum('y','n') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'n',
`date` datetime NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;

INSERT INTO `questions` (`id`, `asker_username`, `target_username`, `question`, `date`) VALUES
(1, 'mikha', 'guy', 'testo festo', '2012-12-22 00:00:00'),
(2, 'mikha', 'guy', 'saaaaaaaar', '2012-12-22 00:00:00'),
(3, 'sys.tem', 'every.one', 'test g1', '2012-12-06 00:00:00'),
(4, 'sys.tem', 'every.one', 'test g2', '2012-12-06 00:00:00');
```

I use the following query:

```
   SELECT        
   questions.id AS questionid,
   COUNT(answers.username) AS count_everyone,
   answers.username  
   FROM questions
   LEFT JOIN answers ON questions.id = answers.id
   GROUP BY questions.id,answers.username
```

The problem is with the `COUNT(answers.username`. I want to count the answers for each question but the query displays the count as 1. For example the question ID 4 is answered 3 times but the `COUNT(answers.username)` displays it as 1 instead of 3.

This is the expected result:

```
         questionid count_everyone  username
               1         1            guy
               2         0            null
               3         0            null
               4         3             guy
               4         3           maricela
               4         3             mikha
```

This is the result I actually get:

```
         questionid count_everyone  username
               1         1            guy
               2         0            null
               3         0            null
               4         1             guy
               4         1           maricela
               4         1             mikha
```

Thanks

Comment: Since you're grouping by username, why would you expect more than one username in each row?

Comment: If i remove the grouping by username, only one answer will be displayed. I want to display all answers and their count at the same time...thanks :)

Comment: maricela only answered question 4 once, so why do you expect the count to be 3?

Comment: the question number is answered by 3 people..so the count of the answers should be 3 not 1...the same person can't answer the same question multiple times..it's the opposite..a question can be answered by different people

Comment: But when you include username in the GROUP BY clause, you're not counting everyone, you're just counting that one user. Why should a per-username row have count for other people? Maybe you should use GROUP_CONCAT to list all the usernames on the row, instead of a separate row for each username?

Comment: Yes I didn't realize that with grouping it will be counted only per username. I need to display each row separately because I want to display the results in a format like a question and an answer..i need to count all the answers because I need to use this number for another purpose. But I need it only when the `question.target_username` equals to `every.one` and only in this case not for all the questions. So would a separate query be more efficient and faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the correct count you should only group by the question id, but not the username:

```
SELECT        
    questions.id AS questionid,
    COUNT(answers.username) AS count_everyone
FROM questions
LEFT JOIN answers ON questions.id = answers.id
GROUP BY questions.id
```

If you *have* to get the usernames in the same query then use a join:

```
SELECT questionid, count_everyone, username
FROM
(
    SELECT        
        questions.id AS questionid,
        COUNT(answers.username) AS count_everyone
    FROM questions
    LEFT JOIN answers ON questions.id = answers.id
    GROUP BY questions.id
) T1
LEFT JOIN answers ON T1.questionid = answers.id
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/73ff3/11)

or `GROUP_CONCAT`:

```
SELECT        
    questions.id AS questionid,
    COUNT(answers.username) AS count_everyone,
    GROUP_CONCAT(answers.username) AS usernames
FROM questions
LEFT JOIN answers ON questions.id = answers.id
GROUP BY questions.id
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/73ff3/14)

Or a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT        
    questions.id AS questionid,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM answers WHERE questions.id = answers.id) AS count_everyone,
    answers.username
FROM questions
LEFT JOIN answers ON questions.id = answers.id
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/73ff3/16)

Comment: +1, but I think argument of `count` shouldn't be "username". As far as I understand the question, it doesn't matter if the person who answered has a username.

Comment: If I group by question id only, only 1 answer will be displayed :)

Comment: This count is needed only when `questions.target_username` equals `every.one` not for all questions. So do you recommend more doing it in a separate query as it's occasional??

Comment: @a1ex07: According to the `answers.username` is not nullable, so your concern about users without a username doesn't appear to be relevant here. I think the argument to `COUNT` is fine.

Comment: @MichaelSamuel: I just don't like the result format. I really don't think it's possible to do this in a nice way with your current  requirements. I've shown one clean approach that uses two queries and  three options for oen wquery, but I would not advise you to choose any of the single query approaches.

Comment: So a separate query would perform better?

Comment: It's not just about performance, it about creating a maintainable system. Is performance a real issue? If it is, have you considered using indexes and caching? I'd start there first. Also, there is no guarantee that one query will be faster than two - two simple queries can sometimes run faster than one complex query. You should measure it if you think it matters.

Comment: I'm still working on the system so I have yet to test the performance. I plan to insert huge mysql data like million rows to see if any performance issues would appear. What sucks about this currently so that I can avoid or change it?? thanks :)

Comment: @MichaelSamuel: Well the result set is hard to read for humans. It's confusing to have the count repeated multiple times. You'll have to reformat your results in a more logical way before displaying it to users. But it's probably also going to be messy writing a parser your result set. Have you tried it yet? You'll probably need to remember the previous question id while iterating. So... you have a complicated SQL query and a complicated parser to read the results, and you don't even know if you got a performance benefit or not... Is it worth it?

Comment: What's so complex about that? this is btw the simplified query. Of course result isn't displayed like that to people! would anyone display row mysql data like that on a website..this is just for asking..

Comment: Well it's your code and your choice what you decide to go with. Have a nice holiday season!

Answer (score 4):

```
select q.id, coalesce(j.AnswerCount, 0) as AnswerCount, a.username

from questions q

left outer join

(select id as Qid, count(answer) as AnswerCount
from answers
group by id) j

on q.id = j.Qid

left outer join 
answers a on q.id = a.id
```

Comment: Subqueries I think wouldn't perform well on a large scale. Is there another way to do it without subqueries? thanks :)

Comment: if you want the answer indicated above, you have to do a COUNT per question first.  why don't you try it first then decide how it scales?

Comment: I have many solutions here...i'm just concerned...anyways I'm yet to test...thanks for your answer :)

Comment: +1 this is another way to write it. But you need an IFNULL to match the result set the OP wants. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/73ff3/26

Comment: I'm giving you the answer you requested above.  Which, by the way, is not an expensive operation.  Even if you find some syntax trick, the system has to count all answers per question, how else will it figure out '3'?  If you are worried about performance, decide whether you really need the output you specified.

Comment: @MarkByers, the desired output has nulls listed in it

Comment: @ExactaBox: Yes, the desired output does indeed have nulls... but not in the `count_everyone` (aka `AnswerCount`) column.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

I think you looking for this , it will show all questions id and count all answers , and show all usernames.

[**DEMO SLQFIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/73ff3/51)

Comment: If you check question number 4 in the scheme, you will find it's actually answered by 3 people :) I need to group by `questions.id` because I want to display the question even if it's not answered.

Comment: again grouping by `questions.id` only will not display all the answers :D i want to display all the answers and their count :)

Comment: again this shows only the question once :D I want to show all the answers in separate rows and count all the answers for each question..thanks :)

Comment: i dont know what u downvoted me since im giving you right answer

Comment: i don't know who did that...sorry...it's not me...thanks for your answer @goodmood :)

Comment: I downvoted... at the time (before your final edit) you had 3 queries and 3 fiddles, none of which provided the desired output.  3 strikes & you're out, I guess...

Comment: @ExactaBox i think you should comment first before you downvote , im answering and helping , so better from your side to correct me or comment me and i correct myself. this site to learn and learn other not to judge each other

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
SELECT        
  questions.id AS questionid,
  COUNT(answers.username) AS count_everyone,
  GROUP_CONCAT(answers.username) users
FROM questions
LEFT JOIN answers ON questions.id = answers.id
WHERE questions.target_username = 'every.one'
GROUP BY questions.id
```

[FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/73ff3/38)

Comment: Mark already posted this solution. I could work it like this but I need each row separately not combined like this. I'm thinking anyway to give a unique auto increment to the answers because I assume that would be better on a large scale..thanks @Barmar :)

Comment: If you really need each one a separate row, then ExactaBox's answer is what you should use.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see you should change this:

```
COUNT(answers.username) AS count_everyone,
```

to:

```
COUNT(answers.id) AS count_everyone,
```

as you actually want to count the number of answers with the same ID...

Comment: both give the same result :) `answers.username` is unique also so either this or this...thanks

Comment: my bad, as you group by usernames this doesnt change anything :S